# Google client secrets not found in my android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth

I'm getting a fileNotFound exception in my when i try to get Google Credentials. I'm keeping my json file in the same path as my activities. I cannot find the proper file location anywhere. This is my first go-around with Android development, any help would be appreciated.

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/client_secret.json"; //from the top of class
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secret
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new FileReader(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH));
    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receier = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receier).authorize("user");
}
```